# Fatal error caused by get_theme_mod()

Tags: php, wordpress, debugging

I've been using the WordPress Customize.php functionality to allows users to customize my theme via the admin Customizer. It's been working fine offline in WAMP, but when I uploaded the theme to the testing server I received this message:

```
Fatal error: Can't use function return value in write context in [my url]/functions.php on line 181
```

The line it links to is a reference to get_theme_mod(), and in particular:

```
  $page_data = get_page(get_theme_mod('page'));
```

Do I have to register the 'theme mods' in functions or something?

Answer (score 0):

Right, I've found my issue - and another one has arose that I'm looking into...

For those that read this after searching the web having suffered the same problem, the reason I was receiving this error was because above this I was testing the get_theme_mod with an empty() function. Which, does not work as get_theme_mod is not a variable.

```
if(!empty(get_theme_mod('page'))){
        $page_data = get_page(get_theme_mod('page'));
}
```